# Windows Phone Mango listbox scrolling

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox

I created a simple application with `ListBox` and 1000 very short strings in it. (no explicit `ItemTemplate`).
If i scroll it really fast - there are black holes(CPU cant render fast i suppose).

At the same time if i use `ItemsControl` in `ScrollViewer` - everything is OKay.

Why ? Can i slow down scrolling speed in `ListBox` somehow ? 
Users can get really confused when they are to see these black holes in the screen.

**Update:** Reproduces on device(HTC HD7 7.10.7740). I use databinding via `ItemSource`

Repro project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lgcod878srnctp0/SLTK_LLS_TEST.zip

Repro video(!): https://www.dropbox.com/s/t25dguq0vaa88o9/WP_20111213_113729Z.mp4

Comment: are your strings binding or added in the xaml?

Comment: Sounds to me as you're testing on a emulator. What you're experiencing isn't a software technical problem, as as such we can't give you a answer.

Comment: I test on device(and FYI all performance related things should be tested on device) . U'd better tried to reproduce problem yourself before writing such conclusions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ListBox` has "virtualization" enabled by default (exactly: sort of UI container virtualization), it's not loading the complete list, just fragments. When scrolling, it has to render the items first, and when you scroll quickly, you are noticing this rendering delay. It's achieved by the [`VirtualizingStackPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel%28v=VS.95%29.aspx). The advantage is, it saves Memory.

You can disable the virtualization when using a custom `ItemsPanel`:

```
<ListBox x:Name="YourListbox">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

...but the solution will take up more resources from the beginning. Might become dangerous with long lists.

The other way round, you can [enable virtualization on your `ItemsControl`](http://www.eugenedotnet.com/2011/05/itemscontrol-virtualization-using-virtualizingstackpanel-in-silverlight-for-windows-phone-7/), for a testing purpose, you should be able to achieve the rendering delay ("black holes").

Comment: Thank you! It works! Scrolling became a bit less responsive but that is okay. The sad thing is long initialization time.
You know, i can't actually understand 1 thing. Why can't we use virtualization in pair with controling render speed. So if itemContainerGenerator is not fast enough to do its job we should simply slow down scrolling a bit... 
Thanks again!

Comment: Nice to hear I could help. Haha yes I'm also facing the problem with the long initialization in my app and don't have a good solution at the moment.

Comment: Not only the initial loading time will be long, when you hit the back button to navigate back to your list screen, it's going to take a long time to render as well. My advice is still enabling virtualization, and implement something like a `BatchObservableCollection` (I found it in Shawn Burke's amazing framework http://agfx.codeplex.com/) to display the items one by one (customizable) so when the user sees blank screen he knows the items haven't come down to that point yet.

Answer (score 1):

How long are your strings?  Is it something you can easily and sensibly split into a very brief summary (8 - 10 characters)?  If so you might want to take a look at the [LazyListBox](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/10/12/procrastination-ftw-lazylistbox-should-improve-your-scrolling-performance-and-responsiveness.aspx) which tries to address the issue  (it was intended for more complex layouts than you are talking about, though, so the benefits may be negligible)

Comment: Thanks for answer! Unfortunately it didn't help. Actually im not sure if LazyListBox is relevant any more for WP7.1. MSft improved scrolling in listbox significantly in Mango update and some 3rdparty control are useless now. Probably LazyListBox is too.